# How to add total sum to woocommerce cart section

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, customization, cart, hook-woocommerce

I customized the "checkout" page and added cart section to that page.(Just copy and paste cart table from "cart" to "checkout" page)

I'm using storefront child theme and custom "cart","checkout" page templates are in here.

```
child-theme/woocommerce/cart/cart.php 
child-theme/woocommerce/checkout/form-checkout.php
```

What I want is to add the total sum section below cart table. Something like this.

[image]

How can I handle this one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the total part WooCommerce has another template called "cart-totals.php". 
So you might need to add its content too.

Comment: You can find it at wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/cart